# Show that $f:\Bbb{F}_3[x]\to\Bbb{F}_3[x]$ given by $a(x)\mapsto a(x)^3$ is a group homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Define $f:\Bbb{F}_3[x]\to\Bbb{F}_3[x]$ by $$a(x)\mapsto a(x)^3$$
How do I show that $f$ is a group homomorphism?

Comment: $$f(a+b)=(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3=a^3+0a^2b+0ab^2+b^3=a^3+b^3=f(a)+f(b)$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_endomorphism

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ than
$$
  f(a+b) = (a + b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2 b + 3 ab^2+b^3 = a^3+b^3 
$$
because $3=0\in\mathbb{F}_3$, so $f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)$.
This means $f$ is a group homomorphism.

Comment: We don't really care about $f(1)$. If anything we'd be interested in $f(0)$, but I don't think it's necessary to check that anyway.

Comment: One should write $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$ instead : the $x$ has no role in the expression $f(a(x)+b(x)) = f(a(x)) + f(b(x))$. Also, if you write $f(a + b) = f(a) + f(b)$, you recognize the definition of a group homomorphism : $f$ turns the sum of two polynomials into the sum of their images.